# Symfony2 - Routing with query in routing.yml

Tags: symfony

I wish to enable variables to be added to the URL for a route in Symfony2 ie.

```
www.mysymfonyproject.com/blog/1?style=fresh&rpp=5
```

The documentation talks about generating urls with query, but from what I understand this is for dynamic content in the app?:

```
$router->generate('blog', array('page' => 2, 'category' => 'Symfony'));
// /blog/2?category=Symfony
```

What I would like would be this:

```
_blogList:
pattern: /blog/{page}?{query}
defaults: { _controller: TestBundle:Blog:view ,page:1, query: NULL }
```

But obviously that doesn't work.

Can this be done using YAML? Or do I need to switch my config.yml to PHP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this route (it should work) :

```
blog:
    pattern: /blog/{page}
    defaults: { _controller: TestBundle:Blog:view ,page:1, style:fresh, rpp:5 }
```

---

Then to generate an url like `/blog/1?style=fresh&rpp=5`, use:

```
$router->generate('blog', array('page' => 1, 'style' => 'fresh', 'rpp' => 5));
```

or

```
$router->generate('blog', array('page' => 1));
```

Comment: perhaps I'm missing something obvious , but I don' want to generate the URL from the controller , I want to be able to pass the variables set from the route into the controller. Or am I thinking backwards here?

Comment: Only attributes specified in the Route will be passed as a action parameter all others will be accessible in `$request->query->get('queryVariableName')`

Comment: I was looking at it backwards, not thinking about the GETs. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can access all the query parameters (the parameters that isn't part of the actual route pattern) by doing:

```
$this->getRequest()->query->get('parameter_name')
```

inside the action of your controller that matches the route.

I have some vague memory of there being some shortcut for this (like $this->getParameter() or $this->getQuery()), but I'm not sure since I couldn't find it documented anywhere.